# Ctrl-Alt-Space doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 14.10

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+pretty much everything else works. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> works. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> works. But nothing seems to see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

If I go into System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts and try to assign C-A-S to a shortcut, hitting the chord doesn't seem to do anything (that is, the shortcut isn't assigned), but hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does.

Emacs also doesn't seem to ever receive the key, which is the real problem since Ctrl-Alt-Space is kind of important for certain programming languages. Plan B, in Emacs at least, is the key sequence <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

I just noticed: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> also doesn't seem to be passed to applications, again, including the keyboard shortcuts app in the System Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Unity maps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to Windows > Toggle Shaded State, whatever that is. If you disable this shortcut, then its passed to whatever application is in that window, including `emacs`. It is quite confusing though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but Toggle Shaded State is disabled according to my keyboard settings, and it's still not working.