# Ctrl+Alt+Space not working on Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.10

Similar to [Ctrl-Alt-Space doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/591068/44054), the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is not working on Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10.

There seem to be no shortcut enabled for that particular combination.  And it seems that is not passed to the applications either.

Any way to enable this particular combination?

(In case it is relevant, my use case is for TeXStudio shortcuts.)

Comment: Have you set <Ctrl>+<Alt> for something else, e.g. switching between keyboard-layouts?

Comment: No.  Just the original shortcuts.  However, I can't see one that is only <Ctrl>+<Alt>, nor that one plus <Space>.